# Tensorflow fit KeyError: 'pop from an empty set'

Tags: tensorflow

The model fits without validation data but when I specify validation data it errors.

```
train_text = train_text[0:64]
train_summary = train_summary[0:64]
val_text = train_text[64:96]
val_summary = train_summary[64:96]
history = model.fit(train_text, train_summary, batch_size=16,
                    epochs=1, #callbacks=checkpoint_callback,
                    validation_data=[val_text, val_summary])
```

Output:

```
4/4 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - acc: 8.4005e-05
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-33d8af3a2923> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 history = model.fit(train_text, train_summary, batch_size=16,
      2                     epochs=1, #callbacks=checkpoint_callback,
      3                     validation_data=[val_text, val_summary])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, sample_weight_modes, batch_size, epochs, steps, shuffle, **kwargs)
    258         num_samples = set(
    259             int(i.shape[0]) for i in tf.nest.flatten(inputs)
--> 260         ).pop()
    261         _check_data_cardinality(inputs)
    262 

KeyError: 'pop from an empty set'
```

Can't find anything on this, don't know where to start.